# Origins of Zariski topology

Tags: mathematics, algebraic-geometry

Why did Zariski feel the need to define his famous topology? Was this notion used in one form or another prior to him in algebraic geometry?

Answer (score 8):

Zariski introduced his topology in this paper: *The compactness of the Riemann manifold of an abstract field of algebraic functions*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., 50 (1944), 683-691.  You can read it online [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1944-50-10/S0002-9904-1944-08206-2/S0002-9904-1944-08206-2.pdf). See also p. 79 of his talk at the 1950 ICM: *The fundamental ideas of abstract algebraic geometry*, pp. 77-89 in "Proceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians, Cambridge, Mass., 1950", vol. 2, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R. I., 1952. Scroll down to the volume 2 link for the 1950 ICM [here](https://www.mathunion.org/icm/proceedings).

Some pages about the importance of the Zariski topology in algebraic geometry are [this MO page](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21502/what-is-the-zariski-topology-good-bad-for/21529) and MSE pages [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161884/why-zariski-topology), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55259/did-zariski-really-define-the-zariski-topology-on-the-prime-spectrum-of-a-ring), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-there-a-way-of-working-with-the-zariski-topology-in-terms-of-convergence-limi/53931), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798667/why-was-sheaf-cohomology-invented).
The idea that maximal ideals (not yet prime ideals) in a commutative ring could be profitably viewed as the points in a space can be seen in Gelfand's work in the 1930s, and whether or not that might have had an influence in algebraic geometry was asked on the MO page [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20268/did-gelfands-theory-of-commutative-banach-algebras-influence-algebraic-geometer).

Comment: Oh yes I meant algebraic geometry of course ! (edited). Anyway, thank you fot your answer very usefull indeed.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to account for your typographical error and I added a link to another MO page at the end.

Comment: Very interesting stuff ! Now I understand better the deep reasons of introducing that notion. These reasons are usually not apparent in a first introductory course in algebraic geometry, where the introduction of Zariski topology seems a bit artificial. But it seems that in the end, the ultimate notion is that of Grothendieck topology, which allows to define properly etale coholmology.